# Enable Pull Requests by default on all future branches

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to find a way to enable pull requests on a specific branch. the problem is, this branch gets deleted every end on the cycle (scrum), and created again from the release-branch (it works like a desenv-branch). I don't want to have to enable the pull request on this branch every time it is created, but rather create the branch with the pull request already enabled (protected branch). I need this scenario because we are with with multiple teams, each with their owns desenv-branches, and I would need to set every code owner on the teams as admins of the repository, so they could protect the branches manually, and I don't want to do that.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!